# Responsive Sticky Headers

Tags: 7

I had previously created a front facing page with a table that has a sticky header using Drupal's built in sticker header js.

Now, we are in the process of making that site responsive. To handle the tables we have set an overflow: scroll on the table container to create a horizontal scrollbar for the table.

However, the sticky header (because it is position fixed) does not scroll.

How can I implement Drupal's sticky header in a responsive site.

Code that generates the table:

```
$block['content'] = theme_table(
  array(
    'header' => $table_headers,
    'rows' => $table_rows,
    'attributes' => array(),
    'caption' => '',
    'empty' => '',
    'colgroups' => array(),
    'sticky' => TRUE,
  )
);
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell without seeing the actual site or any code at all, but judging from what I see, you could change your table header to be "position: absolute;" and make the table's parent element "position: relative". That way, it will take the parent as a reference instead of the window.

Comment: Tried that, no go. And it's the default sticky header set up, no customization (other than colors and fonts).

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of that page or some code? Honestly it should work but you might have some css overwriting the sticky header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to attach some additional custom JavaScript to do this. Take a look at the "correct" answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907660/horizontal-scrolling-of-sticky-header-doesnt-working).

**EDIT**: 
I've put together a working version of [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1307128) - which contains a working modification of the tableheader.js to solve the problem of sticky headers not working when scrolling horizontally.

I've created a module with a new theming function that can be used as an alternative to Drupal's `table_theme` to allow for scrolling sticky headers.I also created an example module. It's working great, but may need some tweaking for your case. The modules are not documented (I'll do that later) but you can look at the example. It's self explanatory. It's on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/argiepiano/scroll_sticky_headers).

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Can you provide a working example using the Drupal sticky header?

Comment: I'll try to get to this tonight.

Comment: Is this table created by a View? Is it hard-coded in the template file? As @typologist mentioned above, it's hard to provide an answer without seeing the actual site. IF this table is produced by Views, and the Sticky headers option is selected in the Format Settings for the View, notice that Views produces two separate <table>, one for the headers and one for the content, one with class `sticky-header` and the other one `views-table`.  Is your `overflow: scroll` acting on both classes?

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I don't think I'll have time to look at this for a few days, but this post may help you. https://www.drupal.org/node/1307128. This person rewrote tableheader.js to solve your problem. I would also look at the second answer there, that seems to indicated that the changes in the first answer are not necessary, and shows code that binds a handler defined in tableheader.js to the scroll event of the div wrapper around the table. Good luck...

Comment: That looks promising. I'll let you know if I can get it working or not - thanks

Comment: @Scott, please take a look at my latest edit. I put together a working version.

Comment: I added your theme hook into an existing module with the theme_scrollstickytable function, updated my table implementations and the table no longer renders.

Comment: Rather than adding the theme hook to an existing module, try  installing and enabling the two modules I provided (including the example) as is.  To try the example be sure to also enable scroll_sticky_headers_example.module, then navigate to  www.yoursite.com/ scroll_sticky_headers_example. I tested this in D7 with Bartik and it works fine. You are going to do some troubleshooting yourself for your configuration. There may be some conflicting css in your theme or something else. That's all I can do from here, really. See example at work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iq6cscE84aw

Comment: I will get this to work so I've awarded you the bounty. I just haven't had time to fully test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [Responsive Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables) module. I think this is what you are looking for.

Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Adds a library to allow tables to function better in responsive layouts.
>
> You can manually add the library to any table on the site. You also have the option of using the [Better Views Tables](http://drupal.org/sandbox/minorOffense/1793630) module to configure the responsive table controls through the Views UI.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the corresponding javascript file on the site:

```
drupal_add_js('misc/tableheader.js');
```

actually, [theme_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_table/7) should will do that, but there are some circumstances you need to do it yourself. (depending on where theme_table is called)

Comment: the sticky header is working, but once we add the overflow scroll on the table, it does not.

Comment: sorry - got it wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code in your custom theme javascript.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    /*global jQuery:false */
    /*global Drupal:false */
    "use strict";
    /**
     * Fix tableheader.js Sticky Table headers overflow-x:scroll issue.
     */
    Drupal.behaviors.tableheader = {
        attach: function (context) {
            var $table = $(".table-responsive");
            if ($table.length == 0) {
                console.log($table.length);
                $table = $("html");
            }
            var $header = $(".sticky-header");
            var $header_left = parseInt($header.css('left'));
            $table.on("scroll", function (e) {
                $header.css('left', $header_left-$table.scrollLeft());
            });
            $(window).on("scroll", function (e) {
                $header.css('left', $header_left-$table.scrollLeft());
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```